# How to make sure, that a user stays at the new version of a blue-green deployment

Tags: blue-green-deployment, canary-deployment, aws-global-accelerator

Suppose you have a blue-green deployment and want to test it with 20% of the users with the global accelarator. You configure it, but that would mean that User A, who would be testing the new version of an application will not be redirected to the old version again. How would this be avoided?